# Vim 7.4: Strange behavior with invalid actions

Tags: vim

I have a problem with Vim 7.4 on my laptop installed with Ubuntu 14.04. When I perform any invalid action, I expected that nothing happens, But I always received strange symbols look like quote character appear and replace my text. Or sometimes, in command mode, when I type a command, 'w' or 'b' for example, it isn't jumping forward/back as I expected but the character 'w'/'b' appear until I press ESC that the action perform (with some addition quote chracters replace my text).

Here are two examples:

[image: the cursor is at the begin of text]
[image: after several times I pressed 'h' command]

This problem annoys me a lot, please help me.

Comment: I think your keys are remapped in .vimrc. Firstly, h is for left side movement. But, in your case it moves rightwards. Its seems that, every time when you pressed h, it moves one character forward by replacing the character with a quote character. so, a mapping like the following one has been done in your vimrc or plugin files. :cmap h lr'<ESC>                 So, when you press h, it will move one character forward and replace it with a single quotes. Try starting vim like vim -u NONE filename. And then edit it. If it works, then the problem is with mapping.